# MYSQL / PHP Search not finding all records in Database

Tags: php, mysql, indexing, sql-like

I've really been beating my head on the wall with this one, and I could use some help.  I have a MYSQL database which has less than 900 records.  I've got to do full text search across multiple columns, but it doesn't seem to work.  When I search the "LName" field, it will show some records, for instance, if i search for "Smith", it returns 7 rows, when the database contains 8.  When I search for a single last name "Albritton" it doesn't find it at all when I know it exists.  This is true for many records in the database.  You search and it doesn't appear to exist, even though I know it does.

I was doing SELECT / FROM / WHERE / OR to search across Lname, Fname, City, State, etc, but it would only search LNAME, and still it would only return partial results.

After hours of searching online, I decided to create an Index on the table and do a search index WHERE MATCH search, which works, but I'm still getting the same limited results.  I'm using PHPMYADMIN and have run analyze and repair, but it says it's fine and changes nothing.

From what I've read, with a table this small, I'm better off not using indexes at all, and I'm fine with that, but neither seems to work properly.

Also, the cardinality on all of the indexes I've created is "1" which doesn't seem to be right.

I'm going to paste my search.PHP here.  Please excuse the mess, I've been trying stuff all night.  Any help is appreciated.

```
/* $result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM attorney WHERE lname LIKE '%$keyword%'
OR
fname LIKE '%$keyword%'
OR
phone LIKE '%$keyword%'
OR
bizname LIKE '%$keyword%'
OR
address LIKE '%$keyword%'
OR
city LIKE '%$keyword%'
OR
zip LIKE '%$keyword%'

ORDER BY if(lname = '' or lname is null,1,0), lname ASC, fname $limit"); */
```

```
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM attorney USE INDEX (index1) WHERE MATCH (lname, fname, city, state, zip) AGAINST ('%$keyword%' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

");


$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if (!$result) 
    {
    die("Error: Data not found..");
    }
```

etc...

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `%` in a fulltext search.

Try this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    attorney
WHERE   MATCH (lname, fname, city, state, zip) AGAINST ('+Smith' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Also note that words less than 4 characters long are not indexed and not searched with default `MySQL` settings.

If you need to search for short words, add

```
ft_min_word_len = 1
```

into your `my.cnf` then rebuild the fulltext index.